# React - Prevent child re-rendering in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, slider, render

I have a re-render issue with a slider which appears in every element from a map.

```html
const Attractions = () => {
    const [slide, setSlide] = useState(0)
    const handleSlider = (direction) => {
        if(direction === "right"){
            setSlide(slide + 1)
        }else{
            setSlide(slide - 1)
        }
    }
    const translation = slide * - 110
      return (
    <div className="attractions">
        <Navbar />
        <Header nav={"attractions"}/>
        <div className="attractionsContainer">
            <div className="attractionsWrapper">
                <div className="left">
                    
                </div>
                <div className="right">

                    {attractionList.map(attraction => (

                    <div className="attractionWrapper" key={attraction.id}>
                        <div className="top">
                            <div className="topLeft">
                                <img src="https://holidaystoswitzerland.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Lauterbrunnen.jpg.webp" alt="" className="avatarImg"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="topRight">
                                <div className="title">{attraction.name}</div>
                                <div className="location"><LocationOnOutlinedIcon/>{attraction.location.city}, {attraction.location.country}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="moreInfo">
                                <MoreVertOutlinedIcon/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="middle">
                            <div className="sliderWrapper">
                                {slide > 0 && 
                                    <div className="left" onClick={()=>handleSlider("left")}>
                                    <ArrowBackIosNewOutlinedIcon style={{fontSize: "30px"}}/>
                                    </div>
                                }    
                                <div className="slider" style={{transform: `translateX(${translation}%)`}}> 
                                    {attraction.img.map(img =>(
                                        <img src={img}  alt="" />
                                    ))}
                                    
                                    
                                </div>
                                {slide < 2 && 
                                    <div className="right" onClick={()=>handleSlider("right")}>
                                    <ArrowForwardIosOutlinedIcon style={{fontSize: "30px"}}/>
                                     </div>
                                }
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="bottom">
                                <div className="interactions">
                                    <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon className="actionBtn"/>
                                    <ChatBubbleOutlineOutlinedIcon className="actionBtn"/>
                                    <CheckCircleOutlineRoundedIcon className="actionBtn"/>
                                    <AddCircleOutlineOutlinedIcon className="actionBtn" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="description">
                                {attraction.description}
                                </div>
                                <div className="comments">
                                    
                                        {attraction.comments.map(comment =>(
                                            
                                            <div className="commentItem">
                                            <h4>{comment.user}</h4>
                                            <span>{comment.comment}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            
                                        ))}
                                        
                                    
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

When i get more elements from the attractionList array, whenever i click on the left or right arrow to go to the next slide, all of the sliders from the list will do the same. I figured out that i should use something so that the slide is set only based on the item from the map, but honestly i have no idea how.

Comment: `map` function gives you index of the array as the second parameter. I believe you should play around with this. e.g. pass it in the `handleSlider` function.

Comment: this is a good idea, but i'm a bit stuck trying to implement something from it

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to behave differently, then the `attraction` object should have its own `slide variable` and `setSlide method`. That way you can just put:

`onclick = {() => attraction.setSlide(attraction.slide + 1)}`

Comment: Hi .thanks for the answer. I am not quite sure i know how to integrate that as translation variable is outside of map and i am using it to transform the slider. can you be more explicit?

Comment: You can just directly calculate attraction.slide * -110 on your slider class style

Comment: Having a const translation variable outside the return will just make every slider follow the same

Comment: i thought of that but is has the same behavior. i think is related to the fact that left and right buttons are not unique for each iteration of "attraction" and i dont really know how to make them unique

Comment: Yes, they are not unique but the value for attraction.slide is unique. That alone is enough